# How can I say 'basic information'?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

I'm preparing a presentation and want to start to it with something like:

> Firstly i want give some **basic information** about this topic.

I have found the word **Basiswissen** but it didn't seem right to me.

How can I say the sentence above in German?

Comment: Depending on the details of the topic and the data you're presenting, something like "Eckdaten", "grundlegende Daten" (as Olafant already mentioned), "die wichtigsten Daten" or "Zusammenfassung" (of the data) comes to mind. If you're not too fixed on the wording of "basic data", I'd also think in other directions like "ein Überblick über das Thema" or "eine Einführung in das Thema".

Comment: Both existing comments seem to be short answer attempts. I  would like to learn, in which respect this seems more attrractive than an (even incomplete) answer. See [this meta question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1696) why this is considered counterproductive.

Comment: @Olafant Das wäre wirklich eine Antwort wert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use

> [grundlegende](https://www.dict.cc/?s=basic) Informationen.

*Den Grund legen* means in this context something like *building the fundament (the base) / setting the scene* so your audience will understand what you are talking about.

> Beginnen möchte ich mit ein paar grundlegenden Informationen zum Thema.

Comment: Da kann ich nicht umhin, den Kabarettisten Steimle zu zitieren: "Und damit schaffen wir die Basis für die Grundlage unseres Fundaments".

Answer (score 3):

Since a presentation is known to give nothing but information,

> Grundlagen, see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Grundlage)

seems sufficient. Depending on the context, i. e. the topic of your presentation,

> Problembeschreibung

is also frequently used for describing a solution approach of some kind.

Comment: Why not say "ein paar Basisinformationen"`?

Comment: @Tom Please don't comment but write a proper answer if you think you have one. You could use the comment to tell what you do or don't like about guidot's answer though.

Comment: @Tom Basisinformation is a literal translation which is not used in this context.

Comment: Ich hätte eine ähnliche Antwort gegeben. Das eigentliche Problem liegt nämlich darin, dass man solche Dinge nicht wortgetreu übersetzt, sondern so, wie es in der Zielsprache üblich ist; und im Deutschen sagt man einfach nicht *„Ich gebe Basisinformationen/ Grundinformationen/ grundlegende Informationen“* oder dergleichen. (+1)